# step with <stop> element fails to restart (worked in 2.2.7 and 3.0.6 but not in 3.0.7)

Tags: spring-batch

I have the following job definition:

```
    <job id="test-restartable-job" job-repository="expimpJobRepository" restartable="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

        <step id="step1">

            <tasklet ref="step1Tasklet" transaction-manager="expimpTransactionManager">
                <transaction-attributes propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            </tasklet>

            <stop on="STOPPED" restart="step2"/>

        </step>


       <step id="step2">

            <tasklet ref="step2Tasklet" transaction-manager="expimpTransactionManager">
                <transaction-attributes propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            </tasklet>

        </step>

    </job>
```

My tasklets are as follows:

```
public class Step1Tasklet implements Tasklet{


    public Step1Tasklet(){

    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        contribution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.STOPPED);

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}

public class Step2Tasklet implements Tasklet{


    public Step2Tasklet(){

    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        contribution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.COMPLETED);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

I call jobLauncher.run(job, parameters) twice in succession with the same parameters (you can call jobOperator.restart() the second time with the same results though). Here's the log output for completeness:

```
2016-09-28 16:45:35,210 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor@144] Registering job: test-transaction-job
2016-09-28 16:45:35,257 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor@144] Registering job: test-restartable-job
2016-09-28 16:45:35,456 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher@133] Job: [FlowJob: [name=test-restartable-job]] launched with the following parameters: [{schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, TASKS=null, WIKI=null, SCM=null}]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,457 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob@289] Job execution starting: JobExecution: id=1, version=0, startTime=null, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Wed Sep 28 16:45:35 EDT 2016, status=STARTING, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=1, version=0, Job=[test-restartable-job]], jobParameters=[{schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, TASKS=null, WIKI=null, SCM=null}]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,467 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@157] Resuming state=test-restartable-job.step1 with status=UNKNOWN
2016-09-28 16:45:35,467 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@167] Handling state=test-restartable-job.step1
2016-09-28 16:45:35,477 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler@146] Executing step: [step1]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,477 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep@184] Executing: id=1
2016-09-28 16:45:35,484 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate@470] Starting repeat context.
2016-09-28 16:45:35,485 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate@372] Repeat operation about to start at count=1
2016-09-28 16:45:35,485 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback@69] Preparing chunk execution for StepContext: org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext@74bdc868
2016-09-28 16:45:35,486 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback@79] Chunk execution starting: queue size=0
2016-09-28 16:45:35,489 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope@109] Creating object in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.step1Tasklet
2016-09-28 16:45:35,498 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep@438] Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=0, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=STOPPED]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,501 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep@454] Saving step execution before commit: StepExecution: id=1, version=1, name=step1, status=STARTED, exitStatus=STOPPED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
2016-09-28 16:45:35,503 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate@443] Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
2016-09-28 16:45:35,503 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep@215] Step execution success: id=1
2016-09-28 16:45:35,506 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep@281] Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=1, version=3, name=step1, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=STOPPED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0
2016-09-28 16:45:35,507 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@183] Completed state=test-restartable-job.step1 with status=STOPPED
2016-09-28 16:45:35,508 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@167] Handling state=test-restartable-job.stop19
2016-09-28 16:45:35,508 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@183] Completed state=test-restartable-job.stop19 with status=STOPPED
2016-09-28 16:45:35,509 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob@308] Job execution complete: JobExecution: id=1, version=1, startTime=Wed Sep 28 16:45:35 EDT 2016, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Wed Sep 28 16:45:35 EDT 2016, status=STOPPED, exitStatus=exitCode=STOPPED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=1, version=0, Job=[test-restartable-job]], jobParameters=[{schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, TASKS=null, WIKI=null, SCM=null}]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,510 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher@136] Job: [FlowJob: [name=test-restartable-job]] completed with the following parameters: [{schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, TASKS=null, WIKI=null, SCM=null}] and the following status: [STOPPED]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,557 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator@270] Checking status of job execution with id=1
2016-09-28 16:45:35,720 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator@278] Attempting to resume job with name=test-restartable-job and parameters={TASKS=null, WIKI=null, schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, SCM=null}
2016-09-28 16:45:35,731 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher@133] Job: [FlowJob: [name=test-restartable-job]] launched with the following parameters: [{TASKS=null, WIKI=null, schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, SCM=null}]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,732 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob@289] Job execution starting: JobExecution: id=2, version=0, startTime=null, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Wed Sep 28 16:45:35 EDT 2016, status=STARTING, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=1, version=0, Job=[test-restartable-job]], jobParameters=[{TASKS=null, WIKI=null, schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, SCM=null}]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,734 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@157] Resuming state=test-restartable-job.step1 with status=UNKNOWN
2016-09-28 16:45:35,734 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@167] Handling state=test-restartable-job.step1
2016-09-28 16:45:35,740 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler@217] Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=1, version=3, name=step1, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=STOPPED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
2016-09-28 16:45:35,741 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@183] Completed state=test-restartable-job.step1 with status=STOPPED
2016-09-28 16:45:35,741 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@167] Handling state=test-restartable-job.stop19
2016-09-28 16:45:35,741 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow@183] Completed state=test-restartable-job.stop19 with status=COMPLETED
2016-09-28 16:45:35,742 DEBUG [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob@308] Job execution complete: JobExecution: id=2, version=1, startTime=Wed Sep 28 16:45:35 EDT 2016, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Wed Sep 28 16:45:35 EDT 2016, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=1, version=0, Job=[test-restartable-job]], jobParameters=[{TASKS=null, WIKI=null, schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, SCM=null}]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,744 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher@136] Job: [FlowJob: [name=test-restartable-job]] completed with the following parameters: [{TASKS=null, WIKI=null, schemaName=PUBLIC, targetFilePrefix=projectNameExport-, SCM=null}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2016-09-28 16:45:35,744 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@982] Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@70fb111c: startup date [Wed Sep 28 16:45:32 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

Essentially it fails to restart execution from step2. All the exit statuses from first execution look right. The stop element Spring Batch documentation states:

> The 'stop' element instructs a Job to stop with a BatchStatus of
>   STOPPED. Stopping a Job can provide a temporary break in processing so
>   that the operator can take some action before restarting the Job. The
>   'stop' element requires a 'restart' attribute that specifies the step
>   where execution should pick up when the Job is restarted.
>
> In the following scenario, if step1 finishes with COMPLETE, then the
>   job will then stop. Once it is restarted, execution will begin on
>   step2.

This very same code works fine in Spring Batch 2.2.7 but stopped working after I upgraded to 3.0.7 yesterday. I also did some debugging yesterday and found it odd that FlowBuilder.TransitionBuilder never hits stopAndRestart() method. This particular transition never shows up in the list of transitions either.

What am doing wrong? Has something changed in 3.0.7?

**UPDATE:** I've just verified that everything works as expected in 3.0.6. I suppose it could be a regression in 3.0.7.

Comment: Running into the same thing with 3.0.7 for Spring Batch

Answer (score 0):

I found there is a unresolved bug written up related to this - https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2315.  There is a work around mentioned in the comments of that bug.

Try adding the attribute `exit-code=""` to the `<stop>` element. The default is `STOPPED`. I had a similar issue and this fixed it for me.

I think this (apparently un-documented) exit-status overrides the exit status of the step. So upon restart spring batch attempts to restart at the STOPPED step instead of the step referred to in the  element's restart attribute. It looks like since the stopped step doesn't have a next step defined the job doesn't continue.

It's possible that after BATCH-2315 is resolved this will no longer be an issue.